# Myisam index manual calculation

Tags: mysql, indexing, size

I have a table with 2.5 billion rows and have a binary(16) index which give me a index size of 18G.

So I change the index into mediumint and hopping index size go down 5 fold or so.
But after 3day of conversion , the resulting table index size is 16G.

Am I doing something wrong?
Please help.

This is original table

```
CREATE TABLE  `processedphrase2` (
  `phrase` char(30) NOT NULL,
  `phraseHash` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `score` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `count` smallint(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `urlid` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `position` text CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  KEY `phraseHash` (`phraseHash`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is modified

```
CREATE TABLE  `processedphrase_` (
  `phraseID` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `score` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `count` smallint(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `urlid` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `position` text CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  KEY `phraseID` (`phraseID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!50500 PARTITION BY RANGE  COLUMNS(phraseID)
(PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1000000) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2000000) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 .......
 PARTITION pOther VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) ENGINE = MyISAM) */;
```

Comment: If you have a table of 2.5 billion rows, I would suggest a partitioning scheme for performance, in addition to indexes.  The range of `mediumint` only goes to 16,777,215 which seems small for such a large table.

Comment: mediumint is not unique.